# C console application gives smiley face after loop

Tags: c

Below code produces two smiley faces when I call `case 2` after `case 1` (in other words after one `while` loop). However `printSentence();` works as it should be in `case 1`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

    char *enterSentence();
    void printSentence(char *);
    char *sentence;
    int willContinue = 1;

main() {
    while (willContinue) {
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    switch (a) {
           case 1:
                getchar();
                sentence = enterSentence();
                printSentence(sentence);
                break;
           case 2:
                getchar();
                printSentence(sentence);
                break;
           case 3:
                willContinue = 0; //exit
                break;
                }
    }
}

 char *enterSentence() {
         char temp[999];
         gets(temp);
         return temp;
      }

 void printSentence(char *asd) {
         puts(asd);
      }
 .
 . //more code
 .
```

I wonder what is the problem here, thanks for any help..

Comment: `sentence` doesn't seem to be cleared after each loop.

Comment: Oh! don't use `gets()`. It cannot be used safely and has been removed from the latest C Standard (C11).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`temp` is *local* to the function `enterSentence`. It is created when the function is entered and it is destroyed when the function terminates.

When you return the address of the object (`return temp;`) it still exists and has that address, but it will be immediately destroyed afterwards and the calling function receives a pointer to an invalid location.

Quick and dirty solution: make `temp` a static object that can live since the program started till it ends

```
static char temp[999];
```

Note: `static` is a quick and dirty solution, as I said. It is mostly better avoided.

---

Edit

Slow and clean solution: move the `temp` object to the calling function and pass its pointer to the function

```
int main(void) {
    char temp[999];
    /* ... */
    enterSentence(temp, sizeof temp);
    /* ... */
}

size_t enterSentence(char *dst, size_t len) {
    size_t retlen;
    fgets(dst, len, stdin);
    retlen = strlen(dst);
    if (dst[retlen - 1] == '\n') dst[--retlen] = 0;
    return retlen;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the previous value stored in `sentence` remains as it is.